# AppleScript Beginner: Suddenly it won't create a text file

Tags: applescript

```
set textFile to "/Users/whomever/Desktop/TEXT.txt"
```

Doesn't create a text file anymore. What do I do to make this function work. There is no error.

Comment: Your statement is simply declaring a variable, and initializing it with a text value. Off the top of my head, you can do `do shell script "touch <filepath>"` to create a new file.

Comment: Well when I used it before I could write to a text file. Now my AppleScript is acting weird and not writing text to files. I used you suggestion and it at least created the .txt file so thanks for the info but I still am having trouble writing an array to a text file the way I know how.

Comment: Yeah, I know you are asking this question as part of the bigger problem you are trying to solve in another thread. We can continue the discussion there to keep the discussion organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following AppleScript code is a basic template demonstrating how to create a text file then write to it.

```
property textFile : (path to desktop as text) & "TEXT.txt"

set randomText to "Blah Blah Blah"

writeToSomeFile(textFile, randomText) -- Will Create File "TEXT.txt" If Not Exists

-- Additional Code Here

-- More Code Here

tell application "Finder"
    activate
    reveal textFile 
end tell


----- Place Handler Definitions Beneath This Line At Bottom Of Script -----

on writeToSomeFile(pathToFileToWriteTo, someText)
    try
        set writeToFile to open for access pathToFileToWriteTo with write permission
        write someText & linefeed to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access writeToFile
    on error errMsg number errNum
        close access alias pathToFileToWriteTo
    end try
end writeToSomeFile
```

However, if you prefer a different option using much less code,  this following AppleScript code will achieve the same results.

```
property textFile : (path to desktop as text) & "TEXT.txt"

set randomText to "Blah Blah Blah"

(* If textFile Does Not Exist Yet, This Will Create The File And Write
 randomText To It. Otherwise it will append randomText to the file *)

do shell script "echo " & quoted form of randomText & " >> " & ¬
    quoted form of POSIX path of textFile
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this very poorly worded question. I appreciate your help with a novice coder.